# Can I upgrade ubuntu-desktop from 11.04 to 11.10 using NX?

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, 11.10, nx

Is it possible to do the upgrade while not being infront of the computer, but rather connecting to it via the internet using NX (from NoMachine) ?

Will the upgrade process include questions/prompts when the computer is disconnected from the internet ?

The relevant computer is:

- an ubuntu-only boot (meaning, there's only one operating system and that's ubuntu 11.04)
- connected using a wired network, so wireless will be disconnected when logged out
- set to return to its last state upon power failure
- using the nomachine nx server (same for the client on my macbook)

Answer (score 2):

This person figured it out:

> This "Run the following command" Works!!!
>
> ```
> gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d
> ```
>
> And if gnome-session-fallback has been installed, then this "Run the
>   following command" will also Work...
>
> ```
> gnome-session --session=gnome-classic
> ```
>
> One "Caveat" being the NoMachine NX Client has to be Manually 
>   "Terminated" since it will NOT exit on its own???

https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-users/2011-October/252648.html

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically it should be possible, but I don't remommend it. It is a little bit risky - with bad luck you might loose the connection due to incompatibilities of some required libraries.

I suggest to use a ssh session to do the upgrade using 'do-release-upgrade'.

Answer (score 1):

A Debian or Ubuntu system can be upgraded remotely from a ssh session, even if the upgrade includes replacing the ssh deamon and the kernel (which requires to reboot the system). A upgrade via NX would be technically similar, however since NX is not part of Ubuntu, this cannot possibly be officially supported.

Either find out, how to perform the update via the command line and ssh or try the GUI and be prepared to recover via ssh if something goes wrong.

Let's see, what could go wrong:

- new kernel does not boot on your hardware
- Network could not fail for one of the following reasons

  - after kernel update: driver module fails
  - network-manager doesn't detect your network or expects user interaction (I'm not sure whether using network-manager is a good idea on server-like machines.)
  - incomplete upgrade (after failing to recover from a unrelated problem) leaves network-manager or kernel and modules in a broken state
- NX does not work after upgrade/reboot

The typical Ubuntu upgrade process does not disconnect you from the network unless for rebooting. And network should come up automatically after upgrade/reboot.

Personally, I'd give it a try if the machine is not mission-critical.

Answer (score 0):

I did it and technically it works. However after the upgrade and the reboot compiz segfaults and Oneiric over NX is not usable.
Don't know yet how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same boat as Markus - I did the upgrade over NX and after rebooting my menus / desktop items are missing when reconnecting via NX. If I log in physically behind the machine's keyboard everything works fine, but now my NX session is dead in the water.

I would not recommend doing the upgrade over NX - something seems to get very messed up for the NX desktop, and I'm not sure how to recover it either.